# Travel to USA in cruise ship

Tags: visas, usa, pakistani-citizens

I was born in Pakistan. 
I have been living in Mexico for 3 years. 
Can I travel to the USA on a cruise ship from Ensenada to Los Angeles?

I have temporary residence in Mexico.

Comment: It's not clear what your questions is, but the tag says 'visas' so I think you're asking if you need a visa to travel on a cruise ship to Los Angeles. You will if you wish to disembark. I think you will need a visa even if you don't wish to disembark but I couldn't find an authoritative reference for this.

Comment: I've edited your question to make it clearer, but I made some assumptions about your meaning that might be incorrect.  If so, you can edit your question yourself or post a comment to clarify.

Comment: Your edit does make it clearer, but is it actually possible to book a one-way cruise from Ensenada to LA? Most of the cruise lines I'm broadly familiar with don't usually sell that way; they intend for you to board at Long Beach or elsewhere in the US.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. I am assuming there is any cruise line which offers this itinery.

On the question of visas for staying on board or disembarking:

If you want to disembark, then of course you need a proper visa for the US. If you can produce one, I guess you will not have any issues.

The more interesting problem goes the other way round: Let's assume you are visiting a harbor where you don't have a visa and therefore you would not be allowed to disembark. Some cruise lines make their own rules there ("better be safe than sorry") and won't let you even embark on some itineries if you fail to present a proper passport with visa for the ports visited. So I would double-check with the cruise line.

For example, many US cruise lines require EU cititzens to carry a passport even if only harbors within the EU are on the itinery, so a national ID card would be suffcient.